# Unable to start GUI with Lubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gui, amd-catalyst

Until this morning I haven't any major problem with my computer after updating the OS (Lubuntu) , until the amdcccle crashed not for the first time but this one was special because after this I'm unable to start the GUI ( I have xfce and mate ) on my computer and each time I try to access to my session the screen become fuzzy and log out. 
I tried to delete the config files from the :

> .config/.xfce

but it didn't solve the problem.
Right now I'm connecting from a guest session and it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the open source driver without any problems.

I used this [tutorial](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Saucy_Installation_Guide#Updated_Open_Source_Driver_PPA.27s) to get the open source drivers.

> **Updated Open Source Driver PPA's**
>
> **Ubuntu-X** : This PPA offers the latest stable releases of video
> driver-related components. Follow the instructions at:
> launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates
>
> **Xorg-edgers:** This bleeding-edge PPA offers video driver-related components straight
> from their code (git) repositories. Follow the instructions at:
> launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

You need to [purge](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Saucy_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx) the Catalyst driver, then install the open source one.